# Why does Maven when build created 3 different jar files?

Tags: java, kotlin, maven

Example:
[image: \target folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfAJK.png)]

I've found 3 version of jar files inside my `./target` folder:
`pluginName-version.jar`
`original-pluginName-version.jar`
`pluginName-version-shaded.jar`

Can someone explain to me how they work, why, and what's the difference? I tried to google it but I found nothing

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the plugins you are using in your pom.xml

Comment: Please show the full pom file etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably creating extra JARs with the Maven shade plugin.